# Is there a way to give margin to a background-image in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I need to add a snipped out background image to my html file. So while adding background-image, i cant really find a way to add margin. Please help. Is there a way in CSS to do this?
Example:

```
body {
 background-image: url("paper.gif");
 background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `background-position` attribute.

```css
body{
  background:url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1);
  background-color:#cccccc;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:10px 10px;
}
```

```
background-position:10px 10px;
                    ^1st ^2nd
```

The first value is equal to `margin-left`, while the second value is equal to `margin-top`.